# $index does not diminish its value when ng-if removes an element

Tags: angularjs

My HTML:

```
<section  ng-repeat="Rule in Data track by $index" ng-if="!Rule.is_deleted">
    {{$index}}
    {{ Rule.title }}<a ng-click="removeElem($index)"></a> 
</section>
```

and the controller:

```
$scope.removeElem = function (elemIndex) {
     $scope.Data[elemIndex].is_deleted = true;              
}

$scope.addElem = function(obj) {
    $scope.Data.push(obj);
}
```

There is a functionality of adding/removing objects to/from `$scope.Data`array. Let's say there are two items in $scope.Data; I am removing one and add a new one. Therefore, the items are still two. The problem is that **$index associates the newly created second item with value 2 and not value 1** as I expected (ng-if removes the item from the DOM, isn't it?). Why that? How may I oblige $index to diminish its value if removing an item?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are asking, the `$index` in your case would be correct, "$index associates the newly created second item with value 2 and not value 1" it should be 2, there are now 3 items in the array, `[0,1,2]`. `1` have been 'logically' deleted, but still exists which is they the newly created item has an index of  `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) rather than using `ng-if` in the `ng-repeat`.

```
<section ng-repeat="Rule in (Data | filter: {is_deleted: false}) track by $index">
    {{$index}}
    {{ Rule.title }}<a ng-click="removeElem($index)"></a> 
</section>
```

fiddle showing the difference: https://jsfiddle.net/u6nqrq5o/

Comment: Thank you very much. It works! However, I still do not understand why my version does not work. Any good explanation?

Comment: filter will create a new array that does not contain the items that are filtered out, thus all of the items in the new, filtered array show. Now `$index` will **not** line up with the actual index in the original array as it was doing before.

Comment: I would suggest filtering in the controller after the `removeElem` function is run, rather than in the DOM. Filters in the DOM are bit infamous for poor performance, because they run the filter function WAY more than it needs to be run, due to being apart of the angular digest cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use $index for this, just pass the object to the function.  Also, this is a better use case for a filter rather than using ng-if to hide/show a row

**HTML**

```
<section ng-repeat="Rule in Data | filter: {is_deleted: false}">
  {{ Rule.title }}
  <a ng-click="removeElem(Rule)">Remove</a>
</section>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.removeElem = function(rule) {
  rule.is_deleted = true;
};
```

Comment: This is the better solution. My answer only showed how to use filter. This solution does that and goes on to demonstrate how removing an element will work / should work. I would only add that `track by` should be used and generally improves performance of `ngRepeat`

Answer (score 0):

Using $index should be avoided.Instead of using $index, prefer to pass the actual objects around. E.g. ng-click="removeElem(Rule)"